# Rule on Saving New Comment not triggered

Tags: 7, rules, comments

I want to do some action after saving a news comment which needs comment's CID but I can not do anything after saving news comment!!

I have tested any other actions but none of them triggered by this action.

I have the same problem with the "after updating existing comment".

Only the "before saving comment" action works but I need comment's cid in my code and this value isn't set before saving a comment. So, how can I do my job?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this problem. Attached is an export of a rule which fires when a comment is added to an Article or when a comment on an Article is updated. The Rule simply prints a system message containing the CID so that you can see the Rule was able to access the CID. I have tested this and I always get the message, with the CID, when adding or updating a comment.

```
{ "rules_comment_added_or_updated" : {
    "LABEL" : "Comment added or updated",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules_i18n", "rules", "comment" ],
    "ON" : {
      "comment_insert--comment_node_article" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_article" },
      "comment_update--comment_node_article" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_article" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Comment id = \u0022[comment:cid]\u0022" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that in general you should not be using PHP code except as a last resort. It would be much better to use a custom action or condition instead. Both ways require writing PHP, but a custom action or condition is secure. In any case, neither is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

I used `$comment->cid` in php code instead of `[comment:id]` and it worked correctly.